# To publish build artifacts generated by .NETFW 4.8 web MVC project to nexus,I am using mvn deploy method which gives error,Any another way to do this?

Tags: .net, gitlab-ci, nexus, .net-4.8

Want to deploy artifacts to nexus OSS for dotnet framework 4.8 project uisng gitlab ci-cd,mvn deploy giving error

```
$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -s ci_settings.xml -Durl=$NEXUS_URL/repository/maven-releases -DrepositoryId=nexus-releases -Dfile=sample.txt -DgroupId=$DEPLOY_GROUP_NAME -DartifactId=$DEPLOY_ARTIFACT_NAME -Dversion=$CI_COMMIT_TAG -Dpackaging=zip -DgeneratePom=true
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\QmcgdsKA\0\*\tcspl\sample_dotnet_framework_mvc\ci_settings.xml: expected start tag name and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <\u0... @1:3)  @ C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\QmcgdsKA\0\*\tcspl\sample_dotnet_framework_mvc\ci_settings.xml, line 1, column 3
```

Note:ci_settings.xml and pom.xml are in the same directory where artifact sample.txt is present

searched another method found nuget push but it is only used to upload nuget package to nexus,I want to publish build artifacts.